# Headers are not found after updating CocoaPods

Tags: ios, ios8, cocoapods

I updated CocoaPods today (`sudo gem install cocoapods`). After performing `pod install` the project won't compile anymore. It seems that headers from the pod are not longer found by the project.

Did something change in the recent cocoa pods version(s)?

The following is my pod file:

```
source 'https://github.com/artsy/Specs.git'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '7.0'

inhibit_all_warnings!

pod 'CocoaLumberjack'
pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.20.0'
pod 'RestKit/Testing'
pod 'NLTHTTPStubServer'
pod 'Appsee'

pod 'google-plus-ios-sdk', '1.7.0'
```

Comment: Assuming that you are on version 0.34.2. What error message do you get after `pod install`?

Comment: at first i got the following error: [!] The use of implicit sources has been deprecated. To continue using all of the sources currently on your machine, add the following to the top of your Podfile:

    source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. Hopefully, it works for you :)

Answer (score 3):

Fix is simple and the error tells what to do. Add this to the top of your Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/artsy/Specs.git'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
```

Here's the Github issue with more details - https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2515

**Update**

Make sure you create the Podfile in the root of your Xcode project directory. Here's what your Podfile should look like -

```
source 'https://github.com/artsy/Specs.git'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '7.0'
inhibit_all_warnings!

# Pods
pod 'RestKit', :head
pod 'RestKit/Testing', :head
pod 'CocoaLumberjack', :head
pod 'NLTHTTPStubServer', :head
pod 'Appsee', '~> 2.1'
pod 'google-plus-ios-sdk', '~> 1.7.0'
```

In your terminal -

- Update RubyGems   - `sudo gem update`
- Update Cocoa Pods - `sudo gem install cocoapods`

In your project directory -

- Remove pods       - `rm -rf Pods/`
- Install pods      - `pod install`

Comment: It did not fix the issue - headers still could not be found. For example - #import "RKRelationshipMapping.h".

Comment: @ErikSapir Can I ask which all pods you are using?

Comment: i added my podfile content to the main message

Comment: @ErikSapir Hmm. The above comment is very confusing. I updated the answer guessing that you're having issues with RestKit. Can you try that? Please share the exact error message.

Comment: My problem is not with restkit. If i remove the reskit from podfile, i guess errors on includes of other pod libraries

Comment: @ErikSapir Everything seems to be fixed. The errors were probably due to erroneous syntax in Podfile like '~>` missing and compatibility issues.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same position as you, and finally decided to roll back the `CocoaPods` version I had installed (which solved my problem)

Luckily my `Podfile.lock` file was under version control, so I pulled up the file to see what the last version of Cocoapods I had used. The last line of my `Podfile.lock` was:

```
COCOAPODS: 0.33.1
```

So here is how I solved *my* issue

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods

sudo gem install cocoapods -v 0.33.1

rm -rf Pods

pod install
```

Comment: PS: There's always been a debate about putting your `Pods` directory under version control. This is a great example of why you should.