# 'RestKit/RestKit.h' file not found on xcode 6

Tags: ios, restkit, xcode6, cocoapods

I tried almost every solution but that is not working for me. I have Xcode 6 on which I am getting this error. I have updated the cocoa pods also and updated the pod file as well.

After installing the update I have got few lines I am adding below:

```
[!] From now on use `PocketLobbyiOS.xcworkspace`.

[!] The use of implicit sources has been deprecated. To continue using all of the sources currently on your machine, add the following to the top of your Podfile:

    source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'


[!] The `PocketLobbyiOS [Debug]` target overrides the `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `PocketLobbyiOS [Release]` target overrides the `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `PocketLobbyiOS [Distribution]` target overrides the `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.distribution.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] OHAttributedLabel has been deprecated in favor of DTCoreText
Sajs-MacBook-Pro:PockyiOS sk$
```

This what I have in podfile. I have removed podfile and installed again but still same error.

```
platform :ios, '6.0'

pod 'MWPhotoBrowser', :git => 'https://github.com/floriankrueger/MWPhotoBrowser.git', :tag => '1.4.1'
pod 'TestFlightSDK', '~> 3.0.2'
pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.23.1'
pod 'RestKit/ObjectMapping'
pod 'RestKit/Search'
pod 'RestKit/Testing'
pod 'PKRevealController', '~> 2.0.6'
pod 'Mapbox', :git => 'https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-sdk.git', :tag => '1.2.0'
pod 'MagicalRecord/Shorthand', '~> 2.2'
pod 'DDPageControl', '~> 0.1'
pod 'MWPhotoBrowser'
pod 'Reachability', '~> 3.1.1'
pod 'Mixpanel', '~> 2.4.0'
pod 'OHAttributedLabel', '~> 3.5.4'

# ignore all warnings from all pods
inhibit_all_warnings!

post_install do |installer_representation|
    installer_representation.project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'NO'
        end
    end
end
```

### Updated

After reinstalling the pods again Restkit error gone but I am having below error:

> ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/sanojkashyap/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PocketLobbyiOS-euffofwxmoaqxqbfslgkbnhhzdsz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PocketLobbyiOS.app/PocketLobbyiOS,
>   file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked
>   (x86_64):
>   /Users/sanojkashyap/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PocketLobbyiOS-euffofwxmoaqxqbfslgkbnhhzdsz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PocketLobbyiOS.app/PocketLobbyiOS
>   Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PLArticle", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in PLArticleTests.o
>        (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_PLArticleTests)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PLLocation", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in PLArticleTests.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_XCTestCase", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PLArticleTests in PLArticleTests.o   "_OBJC_EHTYPE_$__XCTestCaseInterruptionException", referenced from:
>         GCC_except_table2 in PLArticleTests.o   "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_XCTestCase", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PLArticleTests in PLArticleTests.o   "__XCTDescriptionForValue", referenced from:
>         -[PLArticleTests testExample] in PLArticleTests.o   "__XCTFailureFormat", referenced from:
>         -[PLArticleTests testExample] in PLArticleTests.o   "__XCTFailureHandler", referenced from:
>         -[PLArticleTests testExample] in PLArticleTests.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed
>   with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>
> (null): "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PLArticle", referenced from:
>
> (null): Objc-class-ref in PLArticleTests.o
>
> (null): (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_PLArticleTests)
>
> (null): "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PLLocation", referenced from:
>
> (null): Objc-class-ref in PLArticleTests.o
>
> (null): "_OBJC_CLASS_$_XCTestCase", referenced from:
>
> (null): _OBJC_CLASS_$_PLArticleTests in PLArticleTests.o
>
> (null): "_OBJC_EHTYPE_$__XCTestCaseInterruptionException", referenced
>   from:
>
> (null): GCC_except_table2 in PLArticleTests.o
>
> (null): "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_XCTestCase", referenced from:
>
> (null): _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PLArticleTests in PLArticleTests.o
>
> (null): "__XCTDescriptionForValue", referenced from:
>
> (null): -[PLArticleTests testExample] in PLArticleTests.o
>
> (null): "__XCTFailureFormat", referenced from:
>
> (null): -[PLArticleTests testExample] in PLArticleTests.o
>
> (null): "__XCTFailureHandler", referenced from:
>
> (null): -[PLArticleTests testExample] in PLArticleTests.o
>
> (null): Symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>
> (null): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)
>
> Ld
>   /Users/sanojkashyap/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PocketLobbyiOS-euffofwxmoaqxqbfslgkbnhhzdsz/Build/Intermediates/PocketLobbyiOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PocketLobbyiOSTests.build/Objects-normal/i386/PocketLobbyiOSTests
>   normal i386
>       cd /Users/sanojkashyap/pocketlobbyiOS/PocketLobbyiOS
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.1
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -arch i386 -bundle -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk
>   -L/Users/sanojkashyap/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PocketLobbyiOS-euffofwxmoaqxqbfslgkbnhhzdsz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -L/Users/sanojkashyap/pocketlobbyiOS/PocketLobbyiOS/Pods/Mapbox/Proj4 -L/Users/sanojkashyap/pocketlobbyiOS/PocketLobbyiOS/Pods/TestFlightSDK -F/Users/sanojkashyap/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PocketLobbyiOS-euffofwxmoaqxqbfslgkbnhhzdsz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks
>   -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks
>   -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks
>   -filelist /Users/sanojkashyap/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PocketLobbyiOS-euffofwxmoaqxqbfslgkbnhhzdsz/Build/Intermediates/PocketLobbyiOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PocketLobbyiOSTests.build/Objects-normal/i386/PocketLobbyiOSTests.LinkFileList
>   -bundle_loader /Users/sanojkashyap/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PocketLobbyiOS-euffofwxmoaqxqbfslgkbnhhzdsz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PocketLobbyiOS.app/PocketLobbyiOS
>   -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -lPods-AFNetworking -lPods-DACircularProgress -lPods-DDPageControl -lPods-FMDB -lPods-GRMustache -lPods-ISO8601DateFormatterValueTransformer -lPods-JRSwizzle -lPods-MBProgressHUD -lPods-MWPhotoBrowser -lPods-MagicalRecord -lPods-Mapbox -lPods-Mixpanel -lPods-OHAttributedLabel -lPods-PKRevealController -lPods-PSTCollectionView -lPods-RKValueTransformers -lPods-Reachability -lPods-RestKit -lPods-SDWebImage -lPods-SMCalloutView -lPods-SOCKit -lPods-TestFlightSDK -lPods-TransitionKit -lProj4 -lTestFlight -lsqlite3 -lz -framework Accelerate -framework AssetsLibrary -framework CFNetwork -framework
>   CoreData -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework
>   CoreTelephony -framework CoreText -framework Foundation -framework
>   ImageIO -framework MapKit -framework MessageUI -framework
>   MobileCoreServices -framework QuartzCore -framework Security
>   -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=6.1 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -lPods -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/sanojkashyap/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PocketLobbyiOS-euffofwxmoaqxqbfslgkbnhhzdsz/Build/Intermediates/PocketLobbyiOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PocketLobbyiOSTests.build/Objects-normal/i386/PocketLobbyiOSTests_dependency_info.dat
>   -o /Users/sanojkashyap/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PocketLobbyiOS-euffofwxmoaqxqbfslgkbnhhzdsz/Build/Intermediates/PocketLobbyiOS.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/PocketLobbyiOSTests.build/Objects-normal/i386/PocketLobbyiOSTests
>
> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_XCTestCase",
>   referenced from:
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_PLArticleTests in PLArticleTests.o   "_OBJC_EHTYPE_$__XCTestCaseInterruptionException", referenced from:
>         GCC_except_table2 in PLArticleTests.o   "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_XCTestCase", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PLArticleTests in PLArticleTests.o   "__XCTDescriptionForValue", referenced from:
>         -[PLArticleTests testExample] in PLArticleTests.o   "__XCTFailureFormat", referenced from:
>         -[PLArticleTests testExample] in PLArticleTests.o   "__XCTFailureHandler", referenced from:
>         -[PLArticleTests testExample] in PLArticleTests.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed
>   with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: I helped a guy having similar issues yesterday. Please see my answer, I have dealt with multiple issues - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26321543/headers-are-not-found-after-updating-cocoapods/26321677#26321677

Comment: If you resolved the issue, please update here. Otherwise, can you share your Podfile so that we can figure out where you're going wrong?

Comment: @Sandy : Any solution found?

Answer (score 3):

Try to add Pods.debug into your project -> Info -> Configurations -> Debug, and Pods.release into Release section. I solve my missing 'RestKit.h' problem by this setting.
[image]

Comment: it's not working, I do not all of sudden it's stop working. I have reinstalled the cocoapods. Still same issue.

Comment: @Sandy, could you share your Pods.debug file content and the error when it reports RestKit.h is missing.

Comment: now that is Restkit error gone but other issue seems related to test kit is coming.

Comment: Yes these all pods are selected.

Comment: @Sandy, yes I also met test kit compile error before, you should go through Pods.debug and Pods.release file to see if there is something wrongly configured in these two files.

Answer (score 1):

Try to write your podfile in that way:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
link_with  ['PocketLobbyiOS', 'PocketLobbyiOSTests']
platform :ios, '6.0'

pod 'MWPhotoBrowser', :git => 'https://github.com/floriankrueger/MWPhotoBrowser.git', :tag => '1.4.1'
pod 'TestFlightSDK', '~> 3.0.2'
pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.23.1'
pod 'RestKit/ObjectMapping'
pod 'RestKit/Search'
pod 'RestKit/Testing'
pod 'PKRevealController', '~> 2.0.6'
pod 'Mapbox', :git => 'https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-sdk.git', :tag => '1.2.0'
pod 'MagicalRecord/Shorthand', '~> 2.2'
pod 'DDPageControl', '~> 0.1'
pod 'MWPhotoBrowser'
pod 'Reachability', '~> 3.1.1'
pod 'Mixpanel', '~> 2.4.0'
pod 'OHAttributedLabel', '~> 3.5.4'

# ignore all warnings from all pods
inhibit_all_warnings!

post_install do |installer_representation|
    installer_representation.project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'NO'
        end
    end
end
```

Install pod, and at your project Build Setting->Other Linker Flags, add $(inherited).

Comment: hey I am getting another issue.

Comment: It's issue with freshly check out project also which is running fine for other. any idea?

Comment: Thanks, this one saved my day!
**"Install pod, and at your project Build Setting->Other Linker Flags, add $(inherited)."**